# Is it possible to find out what is accessing the Bluetooth service?

Tags: battery, 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, nexus-6

Is it possible to find out what is accessing the Bluetooth service?  Right now I have an issue in which my phone will drain after about 8ish hours.  The Battery view is showing Bluetooth as the top battery drainer, and if I turn Bluetooth off my charge lasts much longer.  I figure there is a rogue application that is causing this, but would rather not have to uninstall all of the applications until the problem stops to see which one it is, or go back to factory settings.

Is there an app that can show me this information, or are there other tips you can give to find out why Bluetooth is pulling so much charge on my phone?
Nexus 6
Android 6.0.1
unrooted

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same issue.